# How to export content in a RData file to Excel/csv

Tags: excel, csv, export-to-csv, rdata

I am not familiar with R programming.I have got a test dataset for one of my projects which is a RData file.How can I export it to an Excel sheet to view the columnar data.

Comment: [BERT](https://bert-toolkit.com) should have a function for this.